# Show images using Python/tkinter on scaled (e.g. retina) displays

Tags: python, tkinter, retina-display

When showing images from python/tkinter, using code such as:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self.root, image=image)
self.label.pack()
```

the image appears pixelated on a MBP retina, i.e. pixel-doubled in each axis.

Is there a way to persuade tkinter to show the image at 'native' resolution?  If not, what other solutions are available to show the image? Of course the image can be saved a viewed elsewhere but I am after a GUI option.

Comment: You marked the solution correct below - can you describe how you got this to work?  I can find resources on editing plists with python but not on making a plist *apply* to a python app.  Can you do it with just a python/tk script, or do you need to bundle things up with pyinstaller or similar tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Cocoa version of Tk (for example the ActiveState version), you might be able to add something to the plist of your program, see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW10

`NSHighResolutionCapable` YES

But not sure if it works.

If you still use the older Carbon based version, it will not work.