# Why the plots look blurry with "TkAgg" backend on retina screen?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using matplotlib to show plots in a GUI app done with tkinter. I've noticed that plots look blurry on the retina screen of my Mac Book Pro.

Below is a minimal example to reproduce my problem.  Why am I having the blurry plots with "TkAgg" backend? Is there a way to fix this?

MacOS 10.13.2, Python version: 3.6.4, Matplotlib version: 2.1.2, tkinter.TkVersion: 8.5.

Notice that the default "MacOSX" backend produces nice sharp plots. Besides, if I create a tkinter app, other elements like labels, menus are sharp as well, only the plot is blurry.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # Remove this to compare with MacOSX backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib tkinter plots look blurry on retina screen]

Comment: @Nae thanks for the link, but I'm afraid it may not related since they are using Qt4Agg backend and not TkAgg. Besides, they are asking a different thing: they WANT to draw blurred plot, which is quite opposite from what I need. :)

Comment: I am not sure if [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1958/) answers to why as it doesn't seem to be the exact issue but it seems to have a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Nae, it looks like that github issue is closed and there are no solutions that help me. Notice that matplot lib produces sharp plots by default when it uses "MacOSX". So the problem must be in the "TkAgg" backend, I think.

Comment: Isn't that more of a general issue with the retina thing, that it scales everything by doubling the pixels? E.g. what happens if you create a TK application with an image in it, wouldn't that also be blurry? In that sense I doubt it is an issue with matplotlib itself.

Comment: The fact that labels and menues are sharp has nothing to do with the graphics. As said, create a tkinter app with an image inside to convince yourself that this is not a matplotlib issue but a general issue with the retina thing doubling the pixels and trying to interpolate them once doubled. There might be solutions to this, but since it's not specific to matplotlib you might be better off taking a broader look around.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest good point. Why do you think there is no issue when I use "MacOSX" backend?

Comment: Because macos backend is written in cocoa and takes care of producing nice graphics on the mac, while tkagg is just the usual tk implementation. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318172/show-images-using-python-tkinter-on-scaled-e-g-retina-displays). I would think it would be possible to write something like a "MacTk" backend, which solves this problem, but this is simply not available as of today.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Do you know where/how can I reach people who maintain tkinter to report this?

Comment: This issue is currently being discussed on the [matplotlib issue tracker #10388](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10388).